# How to remove white screen in between flutter -release build

Tags: flutter, dart

I had a problem with flutter -release build. I had a splash screen and then after that It should show some progress loading bar before it loaded my webview. In debug my code work perfectly, but after I use it on release apk. It will show white screen in between instead and the progressbar is not shown but will directly go to my webview page instead. I already add internet.Permision into manifest, the problem only occur in release but not in debug.

Here my code for reference:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: InAppView(),
    );
  }
}

class InAppView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _InAppViewState();
  }
}

class _InAppViewState extends State<InAppView> {
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    subscription = Connectivity()
        .onConnectivityChanged
        .listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      if (result != ConnectivityResult.none && webView != null) {
        _loadError = false;
        webView.reload();
      }
    });
  }

  num position = 1;

  final key = UniqueKey();

  doneLoading(String A) {
    setState(() {
      position = 0;
    });
  }

  startLoading(String A) {
    setState(() {
      position = 1;
    });
  }

  InAppWebViewController webView;
  int _page = 2;
  bool _loadError = false;
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> subscription;

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    subscription.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _page,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
            child: InAppWebView(
              initialUrl: "https://flutter.dev/",
              initialHeaders: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
              },
              initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                  crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                debuggingEnabled: true,
              )),
              onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                webView = controller;
              },
              onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
              onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
                setState(() {
                  if (!_loadError) {
                    _page = 0;
                  } else {
                    _page = 1;
                  }
                });
              },
              onLoadError: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url,
                  int code, String message) async {
                print("error $url: $code, $message");
                _loadError = true;
              },
              onLoadHttpError: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url,
                  int statusCode, String description) async {
                print("HTTP error $url: $statusCode, $description");
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Some error occured !!"),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is your full code?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede Yes it is. This is the only code for my apps as i only need webview with splash screen

Answer (score 0):

Try with below lines may be it will works for you.

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Also change your `minSdkVersion` to `17` or `19`. After that you need to add

```
<meta-data
  android:name="flutterEmbedding"
  android:value="2" />
```

above lines into your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. I hope this solution is works for you.

Comment: I already try the above solution. Still has the same problem

Comment: Please let me know which version you are using of `flutter_inappwebview`

Comment: flutter_inappwebview: ^4.0.0+4

Comment: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` have you added this into your android manifest file?

Comment: Ok i just added it, the problem still the same